# HQL request in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hql

I'm trying to write an HQL request between the tables Projet, Action, Depense:

```
public class Projet{
    public int id;
    private String libelle;
    private String site;
    private String finalite;
     private Set<Action> actions;
}

public class Action{
        private int idAction;
        private String intituleA;
        private String budget_reel;
        private Projet projet;
        private Set<Depense> depenses;
}

public class Depense{
        private int idDepense;
        private String montant;     
        private Action action;
}
```

I want to do that in HQL: once i choose a Projet, display all the informations about its actions, and specifically  the value of budget_reel of each its action as the SUM of montant in class Depense. Too many constraints, i m lost! can you help me please!!